# Calculating the ordinal is not working ? really confused

Tags: ruby

Can someone help me because I'm not able to figure out why the following numbers wont work.

22, 23, 32, 33

In the if else statement for example if I enter 22 and I do 22%10 I get back 2 but when I go to the ordinal method it does not go to 2 instead it will return th

```
   def ordinal(right_digit)

    if right_digit == 1
        return "st"
    elseif right_digit == 2
        return "nd"
    elseif right_digit == 3
        return "rd"
    else
        return "th"
    end

end


puts "Enter a number: "
# converts string to an integer
input = gets.chomp.to_i
right_digit = input % 10

puts "That's the #{input}#{ordinal(right_digit)} "
```

Comment: Please use consistent indentation. Most Rubyists opt for two-spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the syntax highlighting, you can easily see that `elseif` is not highlighted as a keyword. That's because there *is* no `elseif` keyword in Ruby. It is spelled `elsif`.

And if you ask your editor to auto-format your code (or you copy&paste it into Pry, for example), you will see how Ruby interprets your code:

```
def ordinal(right_digit)
  if right_digit == 1
    return "st"
    elseif right_digit == 2
    return "nd"
    elseif right_digit == 3
    return "rd"
  else
    return "th"
  end
end
```

In other words, since there is no `elseif` keyword in Ruby, it will simply interpret `elseif` as a method call. It is the same as:

```
def ordinal(right_digit)
  if right_digit == 1
    return "st"
    self.elseif(right_digit == 2)
    return "nd"
    self.elseif(right_digit == 3)
    return "rd"
  else
    return "th"
  end
end
```

So, there are only two cases in your conditional: `right_digit == 1` and `else`. For all digits other than `1`, it will fall into the `else` case and return `'th'`. For `1`, it will fall into the first case, and return `'st'`, and since it has returned on line 3, it will *never* reach the call to the non-existing `elseif` method and thus there will never be a `NoMethodError`.

There are a few lessons to learn from this:

1. **Read the warnings**: your code generates two warnings: "warning: statement not reached" for the two lines with the `elseif`. That should tell you that there is something wrong on those lines.
2. **Pay attention to syntax highlighting**: even the extremely crappy, low-tech, basic syntax highlighting in the Stack Overflow question box already shows your mistake. A proper editor or IDE would be even more obvious.
3. **Pay attention to your IDE**: in my IDE, I get a yellow squiggly line under `elseif`, warning me that the method `elseif` doesn't exist. And again, it also warns me about the code after the first `return` being unreachable.
4. **Use a linter / static code checker**: RuboCop, for example, will also find the unreachable code after the first `return`.

The most obvious way to fix your code is to simply use the correct spelling for `elsif`:

```
def ordinal(right_digit)
  if right_digit == 1
    return "st"
  elsif right_digit == 2
    return "nd"
  elsif right_digit == 3
    return "rd"
  else
    return "th"
  end
end
```

However, there is more we can do. In Ruby, everything is an expression, i.e. everything evaluates to a value. There are no statements in Ruby. So, `if` is also an expression which evaluates to the value of the branch that was taken. Therefore, there is no need to `return` the value of each branch, we can just `return` the value of `if`:

```
def ordinal(right_digit)
  return if right_digit == 1
    "st"
  elsif right_digit == 2
    "nd"
  elsif right_digit == 3
    "rd"
  else
    "th"
  end
end
```

Secondly, the return value of a method is implicitly the value of the last expression evaluated inside the method body. In this case, the last (and in fact only) expression is the conditional `if` expression, so we don't need to explicitly return it:

```
def ordinal(right_digit)
  if right_digit == 1
    "st"
  elsif right_digit == 2
    "nd"
  elsif right_digit == 3
    "rd"
  else
    "th"
  end
end
```

Next, Ruby has a multi-way conditional expression, called a `case` expression which is generally easier to read than a multi-way `if`:

```
def ordinal(right_digit)
  case
  when right_digit == 1
    "st"
  when right_digit == 2
    "nd"
  when right_digit == 3
    "rd"
  else
    "th"
  end
end
```

There is also a different form of `case`, where the different condition values of the branches are compared to the test value at the top using the `===` method (which for `Integer`s is just equality, so it will do the right thing in this case):

```
def ordinal(right_digit)
  case right_digit
  when 1
    "st"
  when 2
    "nd"
  when 3
    "rd"
  else
    "th"
  end
end
```

Lastly, it is recommended that you only use double-quoted strings when you actually use any of the features that double-quoting provides, i.e. string interpolation and escape sequences:

```
def ordinal(right_digit)
  case right_digit
  when 1
    'st'
  when 2
    'nd'
  when 3
    'rd'
  else
    'th'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `elseif` keyword in ruby. It’s `elsif`.

To avoid this kind of typos, one preferably uses `case` in such a case:

```
case right_digit
when 1 then "st"
when 2 then "nd"
when 3 then "rd"
else "th"
end
```

Also, there is no need to explicitly `return` the last statement from the method, it’s done automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Problems like this lend themselves to lookup tables as it makes things utterly trivial:

```
ORDINAL = %w[ th st nd rd th th th th th th ]

def ordinal(n)
  ORDINAL[n % 10 ]
end
```

Now you can call `ordinal(999)` and not have to do anything special in the way of preparation to extract the "right digit".

Answer (score 1):

As Jörg says, read the warnings. For that, run ruby with the `-w` option :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
t.rb:5: warning: statement not reached
t.rb:7: warning: statement not reached
Enter a number:
```

Answer (score 1):

And more concisely:

```
ord = [nil,'st','nd','rd'][right_digit] || 'th'
```

Maybe:

```
ord = ['th','st','nd','rd'][right_digit] || 'th'
```

… if we want `0th`.

As a method:

```
ORDINALS = ['th','st','nd','rd']

def ordinal(nb)
  ORDINALS[nb] || 'th'
end
```

JAVASCRIPT (for code snippet)

```js
const ORDS = ['th','st','nd','rd'];

function ordinal(nb){
  return ORDS[nb] || 'th';
}

let i = 0 ;
for( ; i<8 ; ++i)
{
 console.log(i + " + ordinal("+i+") = ", i + ordinal(i));
}
```